# EaselJS: Adding a static bitmap to a page with position (x,y)

Tags: canvas, bitmap, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm using EaselJS for the first time and am confused as to how to load a bitmap onto the canvas as specific co-ordinates.

First I'm defining my EaselJS stage:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("ad_canvas");
```

Then I'm defining a new bitmap:

```
var skyLogo = new createjs.Bitmap("http://francesca-designed.me/sky-test/logo.png");
```

I'm then creating the `x` & `y` coordinates I'd like to place this bitmap at, and adding it to the stage.

```
skyLogo.x = 56;
skyLogo.y = 115;
stage.addChild(skyLogo);
```

I just get a blank canvas and no errors. I'm new to this, and I don't know what I've missed.

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/rOGyvQ)

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the solution. The Bitmap must be added to the stage first, and then the positioning can occur:

```
var skyLogo = new createjs.Bitmap("http://francesca-designed.me/sky-test/logo.png");
stage.addChild(skyLogo);
skyLogo.x = 20;
skyLogo.y = 208;
stage.update();
```

Comment: The key here is that the `stage.update()` needs to be called to show any changes. Your initial example has no update, so it won't show any content.  You can set the position at any time, as long as you update the stage to redraw it. Additionally, images often take a short delay to initialize so you should wait until it is loaded to update.